# Access values from theme with React Styled System

Tags: reactjs, responsive-design, css-grid, emotion, styled-system

In my React project I am using [Emotion](https://emotion.sh/docs/introduction) and [Styled System](https://styled-system.com) for my Design System and styling.

In `theme.js` I have some values (to create a responsive CSS Grid):

```
  template: {
    xs: {
      rows: 'auto',
      columns: 'auto',
    },
    sm: {
      rows: 'auto',
      columns: 'repeat(2,1fr)',
    },
    md: {
      rows: 'auto',
      columns: 'repeat(4,1fr)',
    },
    lg: {
      rows: 'auto',
      columns: 'repeat(6,1fr)',
    },
  },
```

How do I access those keys from my theme.js so I can use them like:

```
<Grid
  gridTemplateColumns={[
    theme.template.xs.columns,
    theme.template.sm.columns,
    theme.template.md.columns,
  ]}
  gridGap="30px"
>
```

I use already Emotion's ThemeProvider:

```
import { ThemeProvider } from 'emotion-theming';

<ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
```

How does this work with Styled System library and what is best practice here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `useTheme` hook in `@emotion/react` to get access to the theme object:

```js
function Component(props) {
  const theme = useTheme()
  return (
   <Grid
     gridTemplateColumns={[
      theme.template.xs.columns,
      theme.template.sm.columns,
      theme.template.md.columns,
    ]}
   gridGap="30px"
  >
  )
}
```

References:

[1] Theming - UseTheme https://emotion.sh/docs/theming#usetheme